# itertuples indices chosen by column name

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

While working with dataframes with 40ish columns I'd like to choose the column by their name and not their number. Is it possible?

Given these two dataframes:

| Custom ID | value |
| --- | --- |
| cdf | 4 |
| abc | 3 |

| Nodo_Cod | value |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 3 |
| cdf | 4 |

That's what I'm looking for:

```
for i in df_1.itertuples():
    for j in df_cs.itertuples():
        if i["Custom ID"]==j["Nodo_Cod"]:
            print("yes")
            break
        else:
            print("no")
```

Instead of what I know as working:

```
for i in df_1.itertuples():
    for j in df_cs.itertuples():
        if i[1]==j[1]:
            print("yes")
            break
        else:
            print("no")
```

Comment: I suspect you can achieve what you want far more simply and efficiently. But you need to tell us exactly what you're trying to do (including sample output for your given input data)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I made it easy in the proposed problem. For what I have to do, while checking if the two columns values are the same, I have to create new columns with values calculated based on values of other columns of the same row index.

Answer (score 1):

Given your loop, it looks like you're trying to test whether items of `df_1['Custom ID']` are in `df_cs['Nodo_Cod']` and map `yes/no`.

You shouldn't use a loop, but [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df_1['out'] = np.where(df_1['Custom ID'].isin(df_cs['Nodo_Cod']), 'yes', 'no')
```

Output:

```
  Custom ID  value  out
0       cdf      4  yes
1       abc      3  yes
```

Note that `itertuples`' items are accessed by attribute name, which cannot contain spaces. To fix your loop you would need to remove the spaces and to use attributes:

```
for i in df_1.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace(' ', '_')).itertuples():
    for j in df_cs.itertuples():
        if i.Custom_ID == j.Nodo_Cod:
            print("yes")
            break
        else:
            print("no")
```

Output:

```
no
yes
yes
```

Comment: Thanks @mozway. Your last reply it is what i was looking for, identifying columns by name and not by number index